# Cómo reproducir audio en Jquery al carga la página

Tags: jquery, html5

He tenido varios problemas al reproducir audio después de cargar la página, me muestra el siguiente error: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first`. Mi código jquery es para una radio simple. ¿Alguna solución?

JS

```
    var player = document.getElementById('player');
var radio = "https://21253.live.streamtheworld.com/WEB16_AAC.aac";

player.src = radio;
player.volume = 0.1;
player.play();

//Play
$('#icon-c').click(function() {
    player.src = radio;
    player.play();

    $('#icon-b').show();
    $('#icon-c').hide();
});

// Pause
$('#icon-b').click(function() {
    player.pause();
    player.src = "";
    player.load();

    $('#icon-b').hide();
    $('#icon-c').show();
});
```

HTML

```
<audio controls id="player" style="display:none">
                <source type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es bastante autodescriptivo.

En general es considerado una mala práctica el reproducir audio sin el consentimiento del usuario.

Esto significa que el factor desencadenante para que se reproduzca el audio debe ser directamente un click del usuario.

Diferentes navegadores tienen diferentes políticas al respecto, quizá puedas lograr tu cometido agregando el atributo `autoplay` y haciendo el reproductor visible para el usuario.

```html
<audio src="https://21253.live.streamtheworld.com/WEB16_AAC.aac" controls autoplay id="player">
    <source type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```